# Как не выводить лишние символы?

Tags: mysql, sql

Как вывести из бд строки у которых есть символ '1', но при этом также имеется строки с '11', они не должны выводится, like и regexp не сильно помогают, либо я команду подходящую у них не знаю.

Comment: А что на счет строк 111? 10? 01? '1 1'. Вы бы привели пример данных, как минимум

Comment: Смысл в том, что если указал одну единицу, то при этом не должны выводиться другие строки в которых тоже есть единицы, т.е. не должны выбираться строки с 11, 12,111,1111 и тд.

Comment: Должны выбраться строки в которых только одна единица.

Comment: У меня больше вопрос к типу поля. Если это число, то можно просто сделать строгий поиск `column = 1`, если это текст и могут быть значения `string 1`, `string 11`, `string 1 backup`, то подход нужен другой.

Comment: Второй вариант, текст и могут быть значения в нем как вы написали.

Comment: А почему `12` не должно выбираться? В этом значении всего одна единица. PS: отредайтируйте вопрос, добавив в него точное определение задачи.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вашу задачу можно решить с помощью regexp [пример](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/da47d9/2)

Регулярное выражение `[[:<:]]1[[:>:]]` поможет найти все вхождения 1 целиком, вне зависимости от расположения.

Тут `[[:<:]]` - нотация, обозначающая начало слова и `[[:>:]]` - конец слова ([источник](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html))

Comment: Спасибо, не знал о таком.

Answer (score 0):

1 вариант

```
select * from

(select * from table_name
where column like '%1%' ) a

where a.column not like '%11%'
```

2 вариант

```
select * from table_name
where column like '%1%' AND column NOT like '%11%'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE LENGTH(c)-length(REPLACE(c,'1',''))=1;
```